# Slim 3 Write Image as Response

Tags: php, image, frameworks, response, slim

I've been researching this for hours and Google hasn't been any help. How can I use Slim 3 to write an image as the response? No matter what I've tried, the binary data is displayed instead of the image. Here's the first piece of code I tried.

```
$image = file_get_contents("image_location");
return $response->withHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")->write($image);
```

Beyond that, I've added various headers such as Content-Disposition and Content-Length. Tried outputting as base64. If you find a Google result for it, odds are I tried it. Nothing works. Of course this simple PHP works fine in a standalone file, but not in Slim.

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
readfile("image_location");
```

My guess is that when Slim outputs it does something to the data, but I'm not sure. Worst case scenario I just create a template and output the base 64 as an img src. I was trying to avoid that.

**UPDATE** After some investigation it seems like the content-type is being reset to text/html, but I'm not sure why. Any insight is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are curious, I found the solution. I traced it down to my middleware in which I had $next($request, $response); however I neglected to assign the return value to $response, so Slim was setting the response to default values.

Now I know to make sure middleware includes the following:

```
$response = $next($request, $response);
```